# JSch exception when using ssh

Tags: java, linux, ssh, jsch

I am using JSch to connect to a remote host using ssh private key.

```
private JSch conn = new JSch();
private Session session = null;
private Properties myConfig = new Properties();
conn.addIdentity( "/home/dummy/.ssh/id_rsa");
System.out.println("Host: " + host);
System.out.println("User :" + user);
session = conn.getSession(user, host, 22);
myConfig.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(myConfig);
session.connect();
```

I manually tried to ssh to that host and it works successfully. But, if I execute this Java program, it fails to connect and throws exception. I am passing a private key as input to addIdentity. The keys are generated using openssh(ssh-keygen). This is my error stack

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
```